# Reactjs problem routing with paramters in URL

Tags: reactjs

Using ReactJS, I am having a problem routing with parameters.  Removing said parameters from the routes causes the code to work but I need the contents of the parameter being passed.  The following code does not work and I can't figure out why:

```
const AppMain = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navmenu">
        <NavLink to="/main/messaging/123" activeClassName="selected">Messaging</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/main/files/123" activeClassName="selected">Files</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/main/payledger/123" activeClassName="selected">PayLedger</NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className="apparea">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/messaging/:token" component={Messaging}></Route>
          <Route path="/files/:token" component={Files}></Route>
          <Route path="/payledger:token" component={PayLedger}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/main" component={AppMain}></Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

I have a mock-up here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-sun-2cexb?file=/src/App.js:251-1110

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You had some mistakes with URLs that you defined for both `NavLink`s and `Route`.

In `AppMain` your `Route` components needed to have `/main` as prefix for all routes.

In `App` you needed to remove `exact` as prop from `Route` because of that your main component didn't render because it needed exactly `/main`, and your routes have different URLs.

Here is your code example with changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-fog-sftyw

Bellow I added `// CHANGE` commend on every line I made changes to:

```js
const AppMain = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navmenu">
        <NavLink to="/main/messaging/123" activeClassName="selected">
          Messaging
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/main/files/123" activeClassName="selected">
          Files
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/main/payledger/123" activeClassName="selected">
          PayLedger
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className="apparea">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/main/messaging/:token" component={Messaging}></Route> // CHANGE
          <Route path="/main/files/:token" component={Files}></Route> // CHANGE
          <Route path="/main/payledger/:token" component={PayLedger}></Route> // CHANGE
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/main" component={AppMain}></Route> // CHANGE
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: In this example  `/main/payledger` didn't show component!

Comment: That is because you need `/:id` `/main/payledger/123` to see that page

Comment: Your question was how to have your routes rendered that you have in `Switch`. Is there something else you need? Do you want to have page `/main/payledger` to open your `PayLedger` component?

Comment: I'm just asking! I'm not the author of the question.

Comment: Ah sorry :), I tought you had a follow u question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to do that:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <div className="apparea">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={["/", "/main"]} component={AppMain} />
      <Route
        path={["/main/messaging", "/main/messaging/:token"]}
        component={Messaging}
      />
      <Route path={["/main/files", "/main/files/:token"]} component={Files} />
      <Route
        path={["/main/payledger", "/main/payledger/:token"]}
        component={PayLedger}
      />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

const NavLinks = () => (
  <div className="navmenu">
    <NavLink to="/main" activeClassName="selected">
      Main
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/main/messaging/123" activeClassName="selected">
      Messaging
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/main/files/123" activeClassName="selected">
      Files
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/main/payledger/123" activeClassName="selected">
      PayLedger
    </NavLink>
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavLinks />
      <AppRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sammet-2m16t?file=/src/App.js)